# Selecting Values from a For Loop Dataframe Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How do I get the row of the below csv's highest price from the result retrieved in the for loop any references or solutions ?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.read_csv('/Users/caleb/ic/US_FINAL.csv',names=['ProductName', 'Year', 'Production', 'Price'])
df.set_index("ProductName",inplace=True)
products=['FortuneCookie']
for product in products:
     print(df.loc[product])
```

Comment: Can you provide a small example of the data and the outcome you are hoping to get? I'm pretty sure you want `.idxmax` but I'm unsure of exactly what you want out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were close. But `df.loc[product]` was not doing what you wanted it to. You want to find where `df['ProductName'] == product`, so the subsets are given by `df.loc[df['ProductName']==product]`. The rest just determines the row where the price is the max.

```
for product in products:
    print(df.loc[df.Price == df[df.ProductName == product]['Price'].max()])
```

Here's a full example if you want to play around with it. If you want to generate this for every Product in your dataframe, you may consider using `df.ProductName.unique()` instead of explicitly defining the list, since you won't have to specify every product individually.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'ProductName': ['Sandwich', 'FortuneCookie', 'FortuneCookie', 'Sandwich'],
             'Year': [2010, 2010, 2011, 2009],
             'Production': [17, 18, 101, 17],
             'Price': [21.11, 17.82, 19.99, 20.13]})

products = df.ProductName.unique()
for product in products:
    print(df.loc[df.Price == df[df.ProductName == product]['Price'].max()])

   Price ProductName  Production  Year
0  21.11    Sandwich          17  2010
   Price    ProductName  Production  Year
2  19.99  FortuneCookie         101  2011
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the df.idxmax() function would your best bet

So for you it would be

```
for product in products:
     temp = df.loc[product]
     print(temp.loc[temp['Price'].idxmax()])
```

Comment: fits the requirement. Thanks Johny Mudly.

Answer (score 1):

I think a simple `groupby` function can get you:

```
# using data from @ALLoLz answer
df = pd.DataFrame({'ProductName': ['Sandwich', 'FortuneCookie', 'FortuneCookie', 'Sandwich'],
             'Year': [2010, 2010, 2011, 2009],
             'Production': [17, 18, 101, 17],
             'Price': [21.11, 17.82, 19.99, 20.13]})

df.groupby('ProductName')['Price'].max()

# alternative
# df.groupby('ProductName').agg({'Price':'max'})
```